# Weird thing with gcc output

Tags: c, gcc, wsl-2

So my homework is to write the program that adds every number until 0 is given and then print out the total.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int sum=0, i;
    do {
        printf("%s", "Enter a number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &i);
        sum +=i;        
}
    while (i!=0);
    printf("%d", sum);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
>>Enter a number: 4
4
>>5
Press Enter or type command to continue
```

But it is supposed to be:

```
>>Enter a number: 4
>>Enter a number: 5
>>Enter a number: 9
>>Enter a number: 0
18
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code is fine. The problem must be within your terminal or elsewhere within your environnment. What is your platform?

Comment: BTW: `printf("%s", "Enter a number: ");` is pointless use `printf("Enter a number:")` instead. And while you're at it, try `printf("Enter a number:\n")`.

Comment: I'm using debian wsl2 @Jabberwocky

Comment: And what is the `>>` in your output? There is no `>>` whatsoever in your code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yea, there is no such thing. I thought the output will be easier to read so I wrote that.

Comment: No, it adds confusion. Are you sure you have saved and compiled your code after any changes you might have made?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I did. It worked perfectly in Dev-C++ thought.

Comment: The code is fine as Jabberwocky said

Comment: @EugeneSh. It must be my wsl then.

Comment: @Helper did you try to put a `\n` as I suggested in my second comment?